# restful webservice for sharepoint365-online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services

Sorry to be vague but I want to build a restful webservice for my sharepoint365-online site as I want to be able to do some custom encryption from values sent by an adaptive card.
I can't seem to find any specific 365 documentation, can find articles that use existing webservices (lists etc).
Is it just the same as creating a webservice for an on-prem sharepoint ?
If not can anybody point me to any kind of documentation specific to creating sharepoint-online webservices.
I am pretty new to Sharepoint 365 online so not quite sure about the process for this.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to access data from SharePoint Online:

[SharePoint .NET Server, CSOM, JSOM, and REST API index](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-net-server-csom-jsom-and-rest-api-index)

You can also use the Microsoft Graph API to access SharePoint Online:

[Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0)